# failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .htaccess query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htaccess` code for rewrite my url using apache:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(archive)/(.*)/([a-z]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&type=$2&action=$3&sort=$4&order=$5&lang=fr [NC,L,QSA]
```

This worked and rewrite my url to :

```
http://localhost/cms/archive/gallery/list/all/desc
```

Now i need to add query string (if i have pagination) like this:

```
http://localhost/cms/archive/gallery/list/all/desc/?pagination=1
```

But i see this error

```
Warning: require_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms//modules/gallery/list/archive.php):failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/modules/archive/main.php on line 7
```

How do fix this ?!

Comment: After cms/ there is no string  in the require statement

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS: cms is subdomain and `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/`

Answer (score 0):

This rule

```
RewriteRule ^(archive)/(.*)/([a-z]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ test.php?page=$1&type=$2&action=$3&sort=$4&order=$5&lang=fr [NC,L,QSA]
```

Outputs using `print_r($_GET)`

```
Array ( [page] => archive [type] => gallery [action] => list [sort] => all [order] => desc [lang] => fr )
```

**Notice that the value for type = gallery and action = list**

For this URL

```
http://localhost/cms/archive/gallery/list/all/desc
```

But, outputs

```
Array ( [page] => archive [type] => gallery/list [action] => all [sort] => desc [order] => [lang] => fr [pagination] => 1 )
```

**Notice that the value for type = gallery/list and action = all**

For this URL

```
http://localhost/test/archive/gallery/list/all/desc/?pagination=1
```

Now, there are two fixes in my opinion, either add a slash in rule, like this

```
RewriteRule ^(archive)/(.*)/([a-z]+)/(.*)/(.*)/$ test.php?page=$1&type=$2&action=$3&sort=$4&order=$5&lang=fr [NC,L,QSA]
```

or remove the last slash from URL, like this

```
http://localhost/cms/archive/gallery/list/all/desc?pagination=1
```